Can I add source maps for PrimeFaces JS libraries?
I work on JSF project and I've p:fileUpload element, I want to debug uploading process. Where can I find and add source maps to fileUpload.js, or other PrimeFaces' JS libraries?

I always build PrimeFaces from source when I want to debug something. That won't minify the JavaScripts and allows you to place breakpoints.

example in fileupload.js:
add: function(a, c) {
if (a.isDefaultPrevented())
return !1;
(c.autoUpload || !1 !== c.autoUpload && b(this).fileupload("option", "autoUpload")) && c.process().done(function() {
c.submit()
})
},
is there a way to get meaningful names for these a and c?

Did you build PrimeFaces from source?

after searching: no, I work with browser debugger. so I'll search for building primefaces from source, thank you.
